# WhatsApp cloud API webhook decrypt media type audio

Tags: whatsapp, whatsapi

I'm using [whatsapp cloud api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api) to build a chatbot, I configured webhook, and when the user sends an audio message I get the payload

```
{
  from: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
  id: 'wamid.HBgMOTcyNTI2MzY2NjU1FQIAEhgUM0E3QjE0M0MyMTY5QjM0OTNFNzMA',
  timestamp: '1658939005',
  type: 'audio',
  data: {
    mime_type: 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus',
    sha256: 'Lqg2WcBG7RY4NhzouRYGChsiem7BwyvaRKXrjsD/q/o=',
    id: '715960496164079',
    voice: true
  }
}
```

I'm trying to understand how can I get the URL of the record, and what to do with this data?

I want to build a bot to convert the record to text using API but I'm not sure how this payload helps me.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to access that media then you have to use get media URL cloud API,

1. Get the media URL using [Retrieve Media URL API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/reference/media#retrieve-media-url)

   - pass media id from `data.id` to `MEDIA_ID`
   - pass your access token to `ACCESS_TOKEN`

```
curl -X GET \
  'https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/MEDIA_ID' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN'
```

2. You can't access media directly by its URL, you have to pass an access token to access the media, see the [Download Media API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/cloud-api/reference/media#download-media)

   - pass URL returned from above step to `URL`
   - pass your access token to `ACCESS_TOKEN`

```
curl -X GET 'URL' \
 -H 'Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN' > media_file
```

Comment: here is an example of a video performing this process: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vf0ivWEah38